# AutoMapper populate other properties based on another one

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this scenario

```
public class ObjectViewModel
{
    public int Isn { get; set; }
    public int? APO_Isn { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectModel
{
    public int Isn { get; set; }
    public int? APO_Isn { get; set; }
    public int? CLI_Isn { get; set; }
    public int? EMP_Isn { get; set; }
}
//Configuration of AutoMapper:  Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectViewModel, ObjectModel>().ReverseMap();

//On my controller:  var objectModel= Mapper.Map<ObjectModel>(objectViewModel);
```

Suppose Isn property of objectViewModel equals 53. When I map the objectModel based on objectViewModel, for some reason unknown to me, the AutoMapper are entering the value 53 in Isn (That's ok), but are entering in CLI_Isn and EMP_Isn too and my ViewModel doesn't have those properties.

I did some test, changed CLI_Isn to Cli_Isn and EMP_Isn to Emp_Isn and the problem was solved. But I still do not understand what was causing the problem, that is why 53 is been moved to CLI_Isn and EMP_Isn.

Comment: What does your Mapper.Initialize call look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are triggering AutoMapper's [Flattening feature](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening)

From that documentation:

> When you configure a source/destination type pair in AutoMapper, the configurator attempts to match properties and methods on the source type to properties on the destination type. If for any property on the destination type a property, method, or a method prefixed with "Get" does not exist on the source type, AutoMapper splits the destination member name into individual words (by PascalCase conventions).

Since [issue 402 was fixed](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/402) this appears to be working with underscores as well, which is what you're seeing here.

There is seemingly no way to disable flattening, so you would have to explicitly exclude those properties:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectViewModel, ObjectModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CLI_Isn, src => src.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.EMP_Isn, src => src.Ignore())
      .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your `Mapper.Initialize` includes a call to `RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("CLI_")` or `RecognizePrefixes("CLI_")`? This would make `automapper` ignore "CLI_" when mapping types but not ignore "Cli_".

Comment: I didn't configure this. Just call `AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMapping();` on Global.asax and on this method I have this `Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectViewModel, ObjectModel>().ReverseMap();`